# How to fix coefficients in R for categorical variables

Tags: r, offset

I would like to know how to put offsets (or fixed coefficients) in a model on categorical variables for each different level and see how that effects the other variables.  I'm not sure how to exactly code that.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars <- as_tibble(mtcars)

mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

model1 <- glm(mpg ~ cyl + hp, data = mtcars)
summary(model1)
```

This gives the following:

`Call:`
`glm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + hp, data = mtcars)`

`Deviance Residuals:`
  `Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max`

`-4.818  -1.959   0.080   1.627   6.812`

`Coefficients:`
`Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)`
`(Intercept) 28.65012    1.58779  18.044  < 2e-16 ***`
`cyl6        -5.96766    1.63928  -3.640  0.00109 **` 
`cyl8        -8.52085    2.32607  -3.663  0.00103 **` 
`hp          -0.02404    0.01541  -1.560  0.12995`
`---`
`Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1`

`(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 9.898847)`

```
`Null deviance: 1126.05  on 31  degrees of freedom`
```

`Residual deviance:  277.17  on 28  degrees of freedom`
`AIC: 169.9`

`Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2`

I would like to set the cylinders to different offsets, say 6 cylinders to -4 and 8 cylinders to -9 so I can see what that does to horse power.  I tried this in the below code but get an errror so I'm not sure the correct way to do one unique value in a categorical variable much less more than one.

```
model2 <- glm(mpg ~ offset(I(-4 * cyl[6]))+ hp, data = mtcars)
```

Would anyone help me figure out how to correctly do this?

Comment: `cyl[6]` is the 6th value of `cyl`. Instead, try `I(-4 * cyl == 6)`, or `I(-4 * (cyl == 6) - 9 * (cyl == 8))` for the complete case.

Comment: Tried that.  Got this `Error in glm.fit(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0), weights = NULL, start = NULL,  : 
  object 'fit' not found`

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: This is what I had.  Do you see anything wrong with it? `model2 <- glm(mpg ~ hp + I(-4 * cyl == 6), data = mtcars)`

Comment: You got rid of the `offset()` part.

Comment: Just worked.  Added the `()` around the `(cyl == 6)`.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a fresh R session:

```
glm(mpg ~ offset(I(-4 * (cyl == 6) + -9 * (cyl == 8))) + hp, data = mtcars)
# Call:  glm(formula = mpg ~ offset(I(-4 * (cyl == 6) + -9 * (cyl == 8))) + 
#     hp, data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           hp  
#    27.66881     -0.01885  
# 
# Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  30 Residual
# Null Deviance:        353.8 
# Residual Deviance: 302    AIC: 168.6
```